# Transform plane to XY plane

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, rotation, linear-algebra

I am trying to find transformation matrix, which will allow me to transfer given plane to XY plane. Based on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950702), I have prepared small Python function which does these calculations. However I don't understand why final plane is not in XY.
Could you help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

my input plane ([3d view](https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=0.0973*x-0.1427*y%2B706.9838&xRange=-50%2C%2050&yRange=-50%2C%2050&resolution=26)):

```
390.17 * x + -571.67 * y + -4008.29 * z + 2833797.03 = 0
input = [390.17, -571.67, -4008.29, 2833797.03]
z = 0.0973*x - 0.1427*y + 706.9838
```

It seems to me that to transfer it to XY plane, rotation about X and Y axes should be done (first). The last element is translation along Z axis.

Based on this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950702) I have prepared my function *transform_plane()*. (code below).

As a result function returns new plane: ([3d view](https://academo.org/demos/3d-surface-plotter/?expression=-0.0005x-0.3959y%2B10.3301&xRange=-50%2C%2050&yRange=-50%2C%2050&resolution=26))

```
2.19436115e+00  1.61044899e+03  4.06772244e+03 -4.20201320e+04 = 0
out = [2.19436115e+00, 1.61044899e+03, 4.06772244e+03, -4.20201320e+04]
Z = -0.0005*x-0.3959*y+10.3301
```

It looks like, the plane was only rotated about Y, and to align it with XY, it should also be rotated about X axis.
Does it mean that I forgot about something? or matrix presented in linked answer is not sufficient to get transformation for two different axes?

**EDIT:**
Thanks to answer below I was able to find missing square root, however still I don't understand why my translation is not sufficient.
Instead of Z = 0, my result is Z = 10. It seems to me that maybe `-d/c` should also be divided by square root.

My implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def calc_cos_phi(a, b, c):
    return c / sqrt(a*a + b*b + c*c)


def calc_sin_phi(a, b, c):
    return sqrt((a*a + b*b) / (a*a + b*b + c*c))


def calc_u1(a, b, c):
    return b / (a*a + b*b)


def calc_u2(a, b, c):
    return -a / sqrt(a*a + b*b)


def get_transform_matrix(plane):
    a, b, c, d = plane
    cos_phi = calc_cos_phi(a, b, c)
    sin_phi = calc_sin_phi(a, b, c)
    u1 = calc_u1(a, b, c)
    u2 = calc_u2(a, b, c)
    out = np.array([
        [cos_phi + u1 * u1 * (1 - cos_phi)  , u1 * u2 * (1 - cos_phi)           , u2 * sin_phi  ,  0            ],
        [u1 * u2 * (1 - cos_phi)            , cos_phi + u2 * u2 * (1 - cos_phi) , -u1 * sin_phi ,  0            ],
        [-u2 * sin_phi                      , u1 * sin_phi                      ,      cos_phi  , -d / c        ],
        [0                                  , 0                                 , 0             ,  1            ]
    ])
    return out


def transform_plane(plane):
    t = get_transform_matrix(plane)
    t_inv = np.linalg.inv(t)
    new_plane = np.dot(plane, t_inv)
    print("new plane:")
    print(new_plane)
    return new_plane
```

Test:

```
plane = [390.17, -571.67, -4008.29, 2833797.03]
plane_xy = transform_plane(plane)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `sqrt` here:

```
def calc_u1(a, b, c):
   return b / (a*a + b*b)
```

should be

```
def calc_u1(a, b, c):
   return b / sqrt(a*a + b*b)
```

Replacement gives `[-1.13686838e-13  0.00000000e+00  4.06760715e+03 -4.19362793e+04]` - x coefficient is almost zero, plane is parallel to OXY (like `z=-1.05`)

Comment: Thank you so much. I checked it a couple of times and didn't see it.

Comment: I am not able to update my first comment... 
I am glad that plane is parallel to 0XY plane, however I was expecting that with translation (-d / c ) - last matrix's column - plane will be in Z=0. What do you think about it?